# Merging rows with same value with conditions for keeping multiple dummies

Tags: r

Creating a subset example of the DF (the code for a part of the actual one is at the end)

```
ANO_CENSO  PK_COD_TURMA  PK_COD_ENTIDADE  MAIS_ENSINO_FUND  MAIS_ENSINO_MED  ENSINO_INTEG_FUND  ENSINO_INTEG_MED  
2011       27            12               1                 0                0                  1
2011       41            12               1                 1                0                  0
2011       18            13               0                 0                0                  1
2011       16            14               1                 1                0                  1
```

I want to merge the rows with the same value for PK_COD_ENTIDADE into a single one, and keep the values "1" for the dummies with the same PK_COD_ENTIDADE. I don't care for the different values in PK_COD_TURMA, doesn't matter which one stays at the final DF (27 or 41).
MY DF have multiple variables like PK_COD_TURMA that I don't care for the final value, the important one are the PK_COD_ENTIDADE and the dummies with value "1"
It would look like this at the end:

```
ANO_CENSO  PK_COD_TURMA  PK_COD_ENTIDADE  MAIS_ENSINO_FUND  MAIS_ENSINO_MED  ENSINO_INTEG_FUND  ENSINO_INTEG_MED  
2011       27            12               1                 1                0                  1
2011       18            13               0                 0                0                  1
2011       16            14               1                 1                0                  1
```

Look at how I have the values "1" for 2 dummies in the first observation of PK_COD_ENTIDADE = 12 and another value "1" in another dummy with the PK_COD_ENTIDADE = 12, and at the end they merged in a single observation for the same PK_COD_ENTIDADE keeping the different dummies "1" (and the same dummies with 1 for different observations don't sum to 2, because they are dummies)

I have no idea how to do this, I searched for some solutions with dplyr but couldn't apply anything close to working...

Here is the structure of the df with all variables:

```
dftest2 <- structure(list(ANO_CENSO = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2011), PK_COD_TURMA = c(27, 
                                                                   41, 18, 16), NU_DURACAO_TURMA = c(250, 255, 255, 
                                                                                                                 255), FK_COD_ETAPA_ENSINO = c(41, 19, 19, 19), PK_COD_ENTIDADE = c(12, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    12, 13, 14), FK_COD_ESTADO = c(11, 11, 11, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     11), SIGLA = c("RO", "RO", "RO", "RO"), FK_COD_MUNICIPIO = c(1100023, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1100023, 1100023, 1100023), ID_LOCALIZACAO = c(1, 1, 1, 1), ID_DEPENDENCIA_ADM = c(2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     2, 2, 2), MAIS_ENSINO_FUND = c(1, 1, 0, 1), MAIS_ENSINO_MED = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1, 0, 1), ENSINO_INTEG_FUND = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ENSINO_INTEG_MED = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample data you give for `dftest2` does not match the data you present at the beginning of your post.

In response to your question, an option is to use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
    . ~ PK_COD_ENTIDADE, 
    data = transform(dftest2, SIGLA = as.factor(SIGLA)), 
    FUN = max)
#P  K_COD_ENTIDADE ANO_CENSO PK_COD_TURMA NU_DURACAO_TURMA FK_COD_ETAPA_ENSINO
#1              12      2011           41              255                  41
#2              13      2011           18              255                  19
#3              14      2011           16              255                  19
#  FK_COD_ESTADO SIGLA FK_COD_MUNICIPIO ID_LOCALIZACAO ID_DEPENDENCIA_ADM
#1            11     1          1100023              1                  2
#2            11     1          1100023              1                  2
#3            11     1          1100023              1                  2
#  MAIS_ENSINO_FUND MAIS_ENSINO_MED ENSINO_INTEG_FUND ENSINO_INTEG_MED
#1                1               1                 0                1
#2                0               0                 0                1
#3                1               1                 0                1
```

Explanation: We first convert the `character` column `SIGLA` to a `factor`; then we `aggregate` data in all columns (except `PK_COD_ENTIDADE`) by `PK_COD_ENTIDADE`, and return the `max` value (which should be consistent with your problem statement).

You can do something similar using `dplyr`s `group_by` and `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)
dftest2 %>%
    group_by(PK_COD_ENTIDADE) %>%
    summarise_all(~ifelse(is.character(.x), last(.x), max(.x))) %>%
    ungroup()    
# A tibble: 3 x 14
  PK_COD_ENTIDADE ANO_CENSO PK_COD_TURMA NU_DURACAO_TURMA FK_COD_ETAPA_EN…
            <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1              12      2011           41              255               41
2              13      2011           18              255               19
3              14      2011           16              255               19
# … with 9 more variables: FK_COD_ESTADO <dbl>, SIGLA <chr>,
#   FK_COD_MUNICIPIO <dbl>, ID_LOCALIZACAO <dbl>, ID_DEPENDENCIA_ADM <dbl>,
#   MAIS_ENSINO_FUND <dbl>, MAIS_ENSINO_MED <dbl>, ENSINO_INTEG_FUND <int>,
#   ENSINO_INTEG_MED <int>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually subsetted the example because i can't paste it properly here.

Such a simple code, you really helped me here, thanks!!